# how to assign memory to a empy string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, buffer

i got an empty string array , with the size of 1 (automatically 1, i dont really know why)

i want to assign a size of 10 to that empty string array, but i dont know how?

this is my code so far

```
char empty_string_array[] = "";

printf("Enter some strings: eg. asdfjklo...: ");
scanf("%s", &empty_string_array[0]);

int len_of_string = strlen(empty_string_array);
printf("%d\n", len_of_string);
```

Input: Enter some strings...: a
Output: current length of the string: 1

restart 
Input: Enter some strings....: ab
***stack smashing detected *** Aborted (core dumped)

I guess that means, there is no memory assigned for more than one string, except the one there already is

i know I could use: char empty_string_array[11] = ""; for 10 strings and the \0 ,, but this isnt really the best solution

Comment: `char empty_string_array[11] = ""; for 10 strings and the \0 ,, but this isnt really the best solution` Why?

Comment: because everyone keeps telling me that, I should use malloc and assign memory instead of using a buffer

Comment: I am not sure that you should be listening to "everyone" then; better get a good book to learn from.

Comment: a good book, that’s like searching for the needle in the hay :)

Comment: but you’re probably right!

Comment: In C all arrays have at least one element, so for `char empty_string_array[]` you implicitly allocated memory for `empty_string_array[0]`; but since there's no explicit allocation that would allow for more elements, well you just crash. I also have the same question @kiranBiradar has.

Comment: @lorde In either case (malloc or static allocation) you should know the how many characters you are going to read in beforehand. You only use dynamic memory allocation when you need more memory and When you want your arry  to persist beyond the scope in which it was created.

Comment: ok, i wasnt aware of that...
ok, if i use the char empty_string_array[11] = "";
I can prevent with an if-statement, that when someone types in more than 10 strings, he gets an error
but if he types in 12, or 13, 15 strings, my if wont work and it start all over again 

if (len_of_string > 10) 
 {
  printf("ERROR\n");
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to use `malloc()` then

```
char *empty_string_array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10 + 1);
//casting from (void *) is not really necessary, though    

printf("Enter some strings: eg. asdfjklo...: ");
scanf("10%s", empty_string_array);

int len_of_string = strlen(empty_string_array);
*(empty_string_array+len_of_string) = '\0';
//or: empty_string_array[len_of_string] = '\0';  your pick
printf("%d\n", len_of_string);
```

Comment: "casting from (void *) is not really necessary, though". Not only is it not necessary, it is highly recommended not to do it. Casting it would hide the error that occurs if you forgot to include stdlib.h

Comment: @FredK: Surely you'd get an `malloc()` undeclared error if you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` — you don't ever compile without options that would prevent that, do you?